# MultiIndex Dataframe to Dict And Keep Data

Tags: python, pandas

My need is to transform the following dataframe to dict like below and keep data as well.

| Name | Firstname | Age | Region | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DUPONT | Jean | 33 | EUROPE | FRANCE |
| PEPIN | Jacques | 42 | EUROPE | FRANCE |
| MARTIN | Eric | 32 | EUROPE | ALLEMAGNE |
| SCHUMACHER | Philippe | 35 | ASIA | CHINA |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

```
{ 'EUROPE' : { 'FRANCE' : [ ( 'DUPONT', 'Jean', '33' ) , ('PEPIN', 'Jacques', '42') ], 'ALLEMAGNE': [ ( 'MARTIN', 'Eric', '32' ) ] }, 'ASIA' : { 'CHINA' : [ ('SCHUMACHER', 'Philippe', '35') ] } }
```

A dict with Region as first main Key a second dict with Country as another key into the main dict.

Don't know if it's possible !

I tried with this function :

```
df_dic = dict([(i, [(x, [y, z])]) for i, x, y, z in zip(df['Region'], df['Country'], df['Name'], df['Firstname'], df['Age'])])
```

but it returns

```
{ 'EUROPE' : [ ( 'ALLEMAGNE': [ 'MARTIN', 'Eric', '32' ] ) ] , 'ASIA' : [ ( 'CHINA' : [ 'SCHUMACHER', 'Philippe', '35' ] ) ] }
```

I lost 2 lines and the second key country is not implemented as a second dictionnary into the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
out = {k: {k2: list(map(tuple, g2.to_numpy()))
           for k2, g2 in g.groupby(level='Country', sort=False)}
       for k, g in df.set_index(['Region', 'Country'])
                     .groupby(level='Region', sort=False)
}
```

Or, the most efficient, using a classical python loop as you originally tried, but with [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
out = {}

for region, country, *info in zip(df['Region'], df['Country'], df['Name'], df['Firstname'], df['Age']):
    out.setdefault(region, {}).setdefault(country, []).append(tuple(info))
```

Output:

```
{'EUROPE': {'FRANCE': [('DUPONT', 'Jean', 33), ('PEPIN', 'Jacques', 42)],
            'ALLEMAGNE': [('MARTIN', 'Eric', 32)]},
 'ASIA': {'CHINA': [('SCHUMACHER', 'Philippe', 35)]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `MultiIndex Series` by converting columns to tuples and aggregate `list` and then in dictionary comprehension create nested `dict`s:

```
s = (df.assign(new=list(df[['Name','Firstname','Age']].itertuples(index=False, name=None)))
        .groupby(['Region','Country'], sort=False)['new']
        .agg(list))

out = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}
print (out)
{'EUROPE': {'FRANCE': [('DUPONT', 'Jean', 33), 
                       ('PEPIN', 'Jacques', 42)], 
            'ALLEMAGNE': [('MARTIN', 'Eric', 32)]},
 'ASIA': {'CHINA': [('SCHUMACHER', 'Philippe', 35)]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most pythonic and cleanest way to do it with pandas but it seems to do the job, and steps are decomposed:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Name": ["DUPONT", "PEPIN", "MARTIN", "SCHUMACHER"],
    "Firstname": ["Jean", "Jacques", "Eric", "Philippe"],
    "Age": [32, 42, 32, 35],
    "Region": ["EUROPE", "EUROPE", "EUROPE", "ASIA"],
    "Country": ["FRANCE", "FRANCE", "allemagne", "chine"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

output = {}
for region in df["Region"].unique():
    output[region] = {}
    df_region = df.loc[df["Region"] == region]
    for country in df_region["Country"].unique():
        df_country = df_region.loc[df["Country"] == country]
        output[region][country] = []
        for idx, person in df_country.iterrows():
            output[region][country].append(
                (
                    person["Name"],
                    person["Firstname"],
                    person["Age"],
                )
            )

print(output) 
# {'EUROPE': {'FRANCE': [('DUPONT', 'Jean', 32), ('PEPIN', 'Jacques', 42)], 'allemagne': [('MARTIN', 'Eric', 32)]}, 'ASIA': {'chine': [('SCHUMACHER', 'Philippe', 35)]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
def to_nested_dict(df):
    # Export nested dict
    d = {}

    # items():
    # t -> flatten index to convert to nested dict
    # v -> last level of your nested dict (values)
    for t, v in df.T.items():
        e = d.setdefault(t[0], {})  # create a new entry with an empty dict
        for k in t[1:-1]:
            e = e.setdefault(k, {})  # create a nested sub entry with an empty dict
        e[t[-1]] = tuple(v)  # finally add values when you reach the end of the index

    return d

data = to_nested_dict(df.set_index(['Region', 'Country']))
```

Output:

```
>>> data
{'EUROPE': {'FRANCE': ('PEPIN', 'Jacques', 42),
            'ALLEMAGNE': ('MARTIN', 'Eric', 32)},
 'ASIA': {'CHINA': ('SCHUMACHER', 'Philippe', 35)}}
```